# How to install a library on the Raspberry pi 3 without internet?

Tags: rpi.gpio, software-installation

I've to install the RPI.GPIO library on my raspberry pi 3, on the other hand, I don´t have acess to the internet in this. I'd already download the library in another computer and put this in my USB flash driver. What I don't know is where I put the zip file in my raspberry and what command I've to run to install it. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: I think Rpi.GPIO is already preinstalled in raspbian jessie, stretch, and buster. So you don't need to installed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, the best way is to use the package manager still (downloading the packages manually), because the installation process will keep track of the dependencies for you.

First, you will need to download the package. You can do it either using the browser from `http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/`, or by adding the content of Raspbian's `sources.list` to another Debian computer and running

```
sudo apt-get download package-name:armhf
```

In your specific case, you likely want either

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/pigpio/python3-pigpio_1.68-4%2Brpi1_all.deb

or

http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/rpi.gpio/python3-rpi.gpio_0.6.5-1_armhf.deb

The links will expire with the next package update, but browsing from the `pool/` folder will get you there. The package name is what comes before the underscore, that is `python3-pigpio` or `python3-rpi.gpio`.

Either way, you will get a `package-name_version.deb` which you will need to transfer to the RPi.

On the RPi side, you will need to install the package with

```
sudo dpkg -i package-name_version.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

There is a chance that the second command will complain about missing dependencies. In that case, note their names, and download the relevant packages as above, then install them too.

Comment: In which folder do I put de archive?

Comment: It doesn't matter in which folder you put the archive. You have to be in that folder when you run `sudo dpkg -i`. Alternatively, you can specify the full path to it: `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`